# Iterating Properties

Tags: c#

I've been doing some research on iterating properties, and have come up with a basic solution that seems to work, but doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. I'm calling a WebService method which returns an PeopleSoft object with a large amount of properties. Each one of these properties returns some obscure type of object that would take too much time to typecast individually. My code works and it iterates the properties, but it doesn't display the values. Here is the auto generated code visual studio makes for one of the properties.

```
public SETIDTypeShape5 SETID {
        get {
            return this.sETIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.sETIDField = value;
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing that the SETIDTypeShape5 doesn't have a proper ToString() method, because when it gets printed, all it shows is SETIDTypeShape5. I know it has a Value property associated with it, but is there any way to access that value? This is the code I have so far, and what some of the output looks like.

```
                Type getType = idResponseTypeShape.GetType();

            foreach (PropertyInfo info in getType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                String name = info.Name;
                object value = info.GetValue(idResponseTypeShape, null);
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", name, value);
            }

SETID = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.SETIDTypeShape5
VENDOR_ID = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.VENDOR_IDTypeShape5
VENDOR_NAME_SHORT = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.VENDOR_NAME_SHORTTypeShape3
VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USR = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USRTypeShape1
VNDR_NAME_SEQ_NUM = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.VNDR_NAME_SEQ_NUMTypeShape1
NAME1 = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.NAME1TypeShape3
NAME2 = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.NAME2TypeShape1
VENDOR_STATUS = VendorMod.edu.clcillinois.fs3.VENDOR_STATUSTypeShape1
```

I'm not sure if I'm explaining it thoroughly, but I'm basically looking for a way to get the Value of each one of those TypeShapes, without manually casting each one to the correct object explicitly. Is this even possible?

Comment: You are looking for an object dumper. A search here on SO will bring up a lot of results.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found an object dumper from Nuget and all you do is call one method and it dumps out the entire object with all the properties. That worked perfectly.